# Change visibility of forms depending on chosen option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a research form which will display differently depending on the choice of a SELECT value. I have applied some jQuery tricks after searching through here. Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="options" id="choice">
    <option value="0" selected="true">Choose...</option>
    <optgroup label='ABC'>
        <option value="1">...DEF</option>
        <option value="2">...GHL</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="MNP:">
        <option value="3">X</option>
        <option value="4">Y</option>
        <option value="5">Z</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<form id="opt1" name="opt1" style="display: none">11111111</form>
<form id="opt2" name="opt2" style="display: none">22222222</form>
<form id="opt3" name="opt3" style="display: none">33333333</form>
<form id="opt4" name="opt4" style="display: none">44444444</form>
<form id="opt5" name="opt5" style="display: none">55555555</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#choice").change(function() {
    $("form").hide();
    $("#opt" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: Did you put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: are you getting error in console?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan at first, i have also tried it but it didn't work either.

Comment: @guradio no error shows in console

Comment: im not sure but demo works with your code https://jsfiddle.net/L51kkfgz/

Comment: your code just works fine check https://jsfiddle.net/o6bsjw2e/

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm quite confused, because until minutes ago, even in jsfiddle, the code didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select').change(function() {
    //var selected = $(':selected', this);
    //alert(selected.closest('optgroup').attr('label'));
     $("form").hide();
    $("#opt" + $(this).val()).show();
});
});
```

DEMO [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kakurala/gpyj2fan/)

Comment: It works! I have one more question: do we really need to place the change of #select in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: No need but the problem is the select element must be loaded in browser while the code runs. If you are placing this code at the end of the document you no need to wrap in $(document).ready(); but its a good practice to run your js code once the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A @guradio suggests, the code works fine in fiddle. To debug the issue try putting `alert`s or `console.log()` to know that the issue it. Hope you have the jQuery library added to your page.

Try these:

```
$("#choice").change(function() {
    alert('fine till here');
    $("form").hide();
    $("#opt" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working,I think you are missing  j query library on form. please add.

see `jsfiddle.net/f5xuc0gh/`